# Django can't load bootstrap

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

The question title describes my problem. I'm currently trying to make it work with static files, but I also tried using Bootstrap's CDN and tried using hard coded path to the Bootstrap CSS. Additional infos:

**settings.py:**

```
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

**base.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="IA">
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/ionic.min.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/ionicons.min.css' %}"/>
</head>
<body ng-controller="LFSTD">
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="bar bar-header">
        <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon" ng-click="toggleLeft()"></button>
        <div class="h1 title">
            <b>
                {% block header_title_block %}{% endblock %}
            </b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ion-side-menus>
            <!-- Center content -->
            <ion-side-menu-content ng-controller="LFSTD">
                <ion-content class="has-header">
                    <div>
                        {% block body_block %}{% endblock %}
                    </div>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-side-menu-content>

            <!--Left menu -->
            <ion-side-menu side="left">
                <ion-content class="has-header">
                    <div class="list">
                        <a class="item item-icon-left" href="{% url 'profile' %}">
                            <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
                            Profile
                        </a>
                        <a class="item item-icon-left" href="{% url 'lfstd' %}">
                            <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i>
                            LFSTD
                            <span class="badge badge-assertive">10</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-side-menu>
        </ion-side-menus>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js'%}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/ionic.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/ia.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone has an idea of why Bootstrap ain't loading? The container and the jumbotron divs simply don't modify the look of the page.

The network monitor gives me 304 on both the bootstrap CSS and JS files:
[image: network monitor]

**Edit:**

Here is my BASEDIR:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Working hardcoded URL:

```
/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

How I call it with static files:

```
{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}
```

URL from view source:

```
href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

**Edit #2, lead to solution:**
After playing around with the static files and the templates, I realized that it is AngularJS messing up my CSS. When I remove

```
ng-app="IA"
```

From my < html > tag, all formatting (except from angularJS of course) works.

Comment: Can you check with your browser Network monitor if it gives HTTP 404 not found? Your browser should generally tell you if it fails to load any resources and then you can simply copy-paste the resource URL on the address bar to see what it spits out.

Comment: I actually get 304's. You can see at the end of my question (edited).

Comment: Can you add `assert os.path.exists(STATIC_PATH)` after `STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` - this should prevent Django start up if you have configured a path wrongly

Comment: I have added that line, but i'm still able to run the server so my static path should be fine.

Comment: HMM. Can you then just go to /static with your web browser and see what it gives.

Comment: /static returns a 404, but at /static/css/bootstrap.min.css I see the css file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75960/discussion-between-lpb-and-mikko-ohtamaa).

Comment: Try use hardcoded `/static/css/bootstrap.min.css` in the `<head>`. If it works then it is issue configuring `staticfiles` correctly.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Might it be because the body block is a ModelForm from forms.py?

Comment: There should be no way it would not work if you copy-paste the working URL from your browser address into your template. Try copy-pasting full urL.

Comment: You're right, my bad. It was working with the hardcoded url. So when I remove the {% load staticfiles %} and hardcode the files it does work...

Comment: So all that remains is to compare the hardcoded URL one to created by `staticfiles` - can you edit both of them into your question?

Comment: Interestingly, when I hardcode it but still load static files with {% load staticfiles %}, it doesn't work. I need to remove all static files and remove the load statement in order for it to work.

Comment: Perhaps try moving the `{% load staticfiles %}` above your `<html>` tag, but making sure to stay below the `DOCTYPE` tag. Do your other static files load correctly? That would indicate that your problem is isolated with the bootstrap css.

Comment: Tried moving the load statement right below the doctype, to no avail. My other static files are being loaded correctly. I'll try another version of bootstrap and then post the results.

Comment: Okay so now when I load the page, the page looks bootstrapped for about 0.3 secs and then loses all css formatting. Update: on multiple browsers

Comment: Use View Source in your web browser and copy URL from there and put it to your question.

Comment: Okay so i've been playing around, and I have probably found a lead to the solution. Please see the updated question.

Comment: When removing angularJS functionality it works perfectly.